# Why do the v19 OCCI RPMs not contain a symlink for libocci.so?

Tags: oracle, occi

The download page for Oracle's Instant Client libraries (https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) has an RPM for the v19.11.0.0.0 libraries (https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/1911000/oracle-instantclient19.11-basic-19.11.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm), but this RPM does not install a symlink for `libocci.so`, why?

Answer (score 0):

Historically the RPMs didn't create sym links even for libclntsh.  Improvements have been made in various versions. The 21c Basic RPM package does create sym links for libocci.

Comment: was there a reason for this? or was it just a bug? also, once the RPMs are installed, what's the correct value for ORACLE_HOME?

Comment: It is history.  Never set ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client - follow the install instructions https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst

Comment: can you fix the download URLs on https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html for older versions? versions >= 18 have direct links to the RPMs that you can just `wget` or `yum install`, but version 12 and older redirect to login pages which are useless on servers.

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible for various reasons.  Luckily you can use current Instant Clients to connect to older databases.

Comment: btw: where can we find release notes for recent OCCI releases, specifically 21.x ?

Comment: By some committee decision, release notes are now centralized in one manual https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/nfcon/index.html There is no specific change for OCCI.  The OCI API gets all enhancements and is recommended.

Comment: "gets all enhancements" what does that even mean? is there a list of changes that are in the libocci at. al libraries' point-releases?

Comment: There haven't been any changes to OCCI in recent versions but we have enhanced OCI.  Note OCCI uses OCI underneath.  You can check older OCCI manuals for changes in the relevant version.  In recent versions of Oracle DB all new features are centralized (for better or worse) in a single Oracle manual.